# How does JIT optimize branching while processing elements of collections? (in Scala)

Tags: performance, scala, compiler-optimization, jit

This is a question about performance of code written in Scala.

Consider the following two code snippets, assume that x is some collection containing ~50 million elements:

```
def process(x: Traversable[T]) = {
   processFirst x.head
   x reduce processPair
   processLast x.last
}
```

Versus something like this (assume for now we have some way to determine if we're operating on the first element versus the last element):

```
def isFirstElement[T](x: T) = ???
def isLastElement[T](x: T) = ???

def process(x: Traversable[T]) = {
   x reduce { 
     (left, right) => 
       if (isFirstElement(left)
         processFirst(left)
       else if (isLastElement(right))
         processLast(right)

       processPair(left, right)
   }
}
```

Which approach is faster? and for ~50 million elements, how much faster?

It seems to me that the first example would be faster because there are fewer conditional checks occurring for all but the first and last elements.  However for the latter example there is some argument to suggest that the JIT might be clever enough to optimize away those additional head/last conditional checks that would otherwise occur for all but the first/last elements.

Is the JIT clever enough to perform such operations?  The obvious advantage of the latter approach is that all business can be placed in the same function body while in the latter case business must be partitioned into three separate function bodies invoked separately.

** **EDIT** **

Thanks for all the great responses.  While I am leaving the second code snippet above to illustrate its incorrectness, I want to revise the first approach slightly to reflect better the problem I am attempting to solve:

```
// x is some iterator
def process(x: Iterator[T]) = {
   if (x.hasNext)
   {
       var previous = x.next
       var current = null
       processFirst previous
       while(x.hasNext)
       {
          current = x.next
          processPair(previous, current)
          previous = current
       }
       processLast previous
   }
}
```

While there are no additional checks occurring in the body, there is an additional reference assignment that appears to be unavoidable (previous = current).  This is also a much more imperative approach that relies on nullable mutable variables.  Implementing this in a functional yet high performance manner would be another exercise for another question.

How does this code snippet stack-up against the last of the two examples above? (the single-iteration block approach containing all the branches).  The other thing I realize is that the latter of the two examples is *also* broken on collections containing fewer than two elements.

Answer (score 2):

If your underlying collection has an inexpensive `head` and `last` method (not true for a generic `Traversable`), and the reduction operations are relatively inexpensive, then the second way takes about 10% longer (maybe a little less) than the first on my machine.  (You can use a var to get `first`, and you can keep updating a second far with the right argument to obtain `last`, and then do the final operation outside of the loop.)

If you have an expensive `last` (i.e. you have to traverse the whole collection), then the first operation takes about 10% longer (maybe a little more).

Mostly you shouldn't worry too much about it and instead worry more about correctness.  For instance, in a 2-element list your second code has a bug (because there is an else instead of a separate test).  In a 1-element list, the second code never calls reduce's lambda at all, so again fails to work.

This argues that you should do it the first way unless you're sure `last` is really expensive in your case.

---

Edit: if you switch to a manual reduce-like-operation using an iterator, you might be able to shave off up to about 40% of your time compared to the expensive-`last` case (e.g. list).  For inexpensive `last`, probably not so much (up to ~20%).  (I get these values when operating on lengths of strings, for example.)

Comment: Indeed computing the first and the last element of the collection is inexpensive in my scenario.  Let's pretend that if we are traversing a linked-list, we don't care about the last element until we get there.  Thanks for taking the time to benchmark, I am still working on a benchmark and will report my results soon for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, note that, depending on the concrete implementation of `Traversable`, doing something like `x.last` may be *really* expensive. Like, more expensive than all the rest of what's going on here.

Second, I doubt the cost of conditionals themselves is going to be noticeable, even on a 50 million collection, but actually figuring out whether a given element is the first or the last, might again, depending on implementation, get pricey.

Third, JIT will not be able to optimize the conditionals away: if there was a way to do that, you would have been able to write your implementation without conditionals to begin with.

Finally, if you are at a point where it starts looking like an extra `if` statement might affect performance, you might consider switching to java or even "C". Don't get me wrong, I love scala, it is a great language, with lots of power and useful features, but being super-fast just isn't one of them.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69536/discussion-on-answer-by-dima-how-does-jit-optimize-branching-while-processing-el).